# How override the OAuthView with a custom view?

Tags: flask, flask-appbuilder

How do you set the provider login as the default login page, instead of being navigated to the OAuth page where you need to select the provider?

Answer (score 1):

I used JS in the *login_oauth.html* page to override the initial load and *redirect* as soon as it hit the page.

window.location = "/login/";

e.g. "http://localhost:port/login/google"